How to create a polar stacked plot with Highcharter in R
With the following dataframe:
df <- structure(list(row_labels = c("La ubicación actual de los contenedores de la ciudad", 
"La falta de limpieza de los solares", "La velocidad a la que circulan los vehículos en la ciudad"
), `Nada problemático` = c(45.1242829827916, 17.3996175908222, 
26.5774378585086), Poco = c(24.8565965583174, 21.7973231357553, 
33.4608030592734), Bastante = c(19.3116634799235, 30.7839388145315, 
23.7093690248566), `Muy problemático` = c(9.75143403441682, 
26.0038240917782, 14.34034416826), `NS/NC` = c(0.956022944550669, 
4.01529636711281, 1.91204588910134)), row.names = c("#Total", 
"#Total1", "#Total2"), class = c("etable", "data.frame"))

I want to create a plot like: 
But I am not sure that the df is well structured because the code that I am using does not work:
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'bar', polar = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$row_labels) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, name = 'Fruits', dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)) %>%
  hc_credits(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_pane(endAngle = 270) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(animation = FALSE))


One option to achieve your desired result would be to add the columns of your data one by one using hc_add_series where for convenience I use Reduce to loop over the columns. Additionally set stacking = "normal" via the plot options to get a stacked radial bar chart.
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

highchart() |>
  hc_chart(
    type = "bar",
    polar = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(
    stacking = "normal"
  )) |>
  hc_xAxis(categories = rev(df$row_labels)) |>
  hc_yAxis(reversedStacks = FALSE) |>
  Reduce(
    \(hc, x) {
      hc_add_series(
        hc,
        rev(df[[x]]),
        name = x,
        dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.y:,.1f} %")
      )
    },
    x = names(df)[-1],
    init = _
  ) |>
  hc_credits(
    enabled = TRUE,
    text = "InvestigaOnline.com",
    href = "https://www.investigaonline.com"
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) |>
  hc_pane(endAngle = 270) |>
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(animation = FALSE))



Thanks a lot Stefan, but how can I modify the colors as I want?

You can set your colors using hc_colors, e.g. hc_colors(scales::hue_pal((5)) for the default ggplot2 colors.

To draw stack you need to add proper series to the chart using hc_add_series with following inputs:

name: Name of the data which will display in Legend
data: the figures
stack: the series with same stack name will be stacked together

Below is two examples
Stacked with one group
highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = 'bar', polar = TRUE) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = df$row_labels) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'NS/NC',
        data = df$`NS/NC`, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Muy problemático',
        data = df$`Muy problemático`, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Poco',
        data = df$Poco, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Bastene',
        data = df$Bastante, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Nada problemático',
        data = df$`Nada problemático`, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_credits(enabled = TRUE) %>%
      hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
      hc_pane(endAngle = 270) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(animation = FALSE))


Stacked with two group
Changes compared to previous graphs:

Order of hc_add_series is different
NS.NC series stack="2"

highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = 'bar', polar = TRUE) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = df$row_labels) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Nada problemático',
        data = df$`Nada problemático`, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Poco Bastante',
        data = df$Poco, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Muy problemático',
        data = df$`Muy problemático`, stack = "1") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'NS/NC',
        data = df$`Muy problemático`, stack = "2") %>%
      hc_credits(enabled = TRUE) %>%
      hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
      hc_pane(endAngle = 270) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(animation = FALSE))



The data frame you're using is structured properly, only the Highcharter code needs a bit of adjustment.
To enable stacking in the chart for all series, you need to set it using hc_plotOptions. Also, each series needs to be added separately and assigned to one stack, so that it's rendered like in the given image.
Try this code in your solution:
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'bar', polar = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$`row_labels`) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>%
  hc_pane(endAngle = 270) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Ns/NC', data = df$`NS/NC`, stack = 'a') %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Muy problematico', data = df$`Muy problemático`, stack = 'a') %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Bastante', data = df$`Bastante`, stack = 'a') %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Poco', data = df$`Poco`, stack = 'a') %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Nada problematico', data = df$`Nada problemático`, stack = 'a')

API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.stacking
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.stack
